# How to get json object in botpress custom component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatbot, botpress

I am calling an api from botpress which returns a list of objects which I need to display in my custom component, but I always get it as string `InfaLinkPreview.jsx: "[object Object]"` if I use `console.log(JSON.parse(this.contentArray))` I get below exception

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at eval (eval at render (VM449 lite.bundle.js:10992), <anonymous>:1:18)
at InfaLinkPreview.render (VM449 lite.bundle.js:10992)
at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14741)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14696)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15644)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19312)
at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19352)
at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19435)
at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20342)
at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20254)
at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20228)
at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:20097)
at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:19911)
at Object.enqueueSetState (react-dom.development.js:11169)
at Web.push../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js.Component.setState (react.development.js:335)
```

It seems I am missing something in the custom component.

Server call api node and Infa link preview node screenshot showing **session.response**
[image]

botpress emulator screenshot showing value of **session.response**
[image]
modules\custom-component\src\content-types\infa-link-preview.js

```
const base = require('./_base');

function render(data) {
  const events = [];
  return [{
    type: 'custom',
    module: 'custom-component',
    component: 'InfaLinkPreview',
    text: data.text
  }]
}

function renderElement(data, channel) {
  if (channel === 'web' || channel === 'api') {
    return render(data);
  }
  return []; // TODO
}

module.exports = {
  id: 'custom_linkpreview',
  group: 'Custom Component',
  title: 'Infa Link Preview',
  jsonSchema: {
    description: 'Displays content of an array of KB/Docs/Video links',
    type: 'object',
    required: ['text'],
    properties: {
      text: {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'Message'
      },
      variations: {
        type: 'array',
        title: 'Alternates (optional)',
        items: {
          type: 'string',
          default: ''
        }
      },
      ...base.typingIndicators
    }
  },
  uiSchema: {
    text: {
      'ui:field': 'i18n_field',
      $subtype: 'textarea'
    },
    variations: {
      'ui:options': {
        orderable: false
      }
    }
  },
  computePreviewText: formData => 'Infa Link Preview: ' + formData.text,
  renderElement: renderElement
}
```

modules\custom-component\src\views\lite\components\InfaLinkPreview.jsx

```
export class InfaLinkPreview extends React.Component {
  noAnswer = "Sorry no answer found."
  contentArray = this.props.text

  getTimestamp = () => {
    let date = new Date();
    let options = {
      month: "short",
      day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
    };
    return date.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("InfaLinkPreview.jsx: " + JSON.stringify(this.contentArray));
    if (this.contentArray[0].query_status == "answer_available") {
      return (
        <div className="linkPreviewMain">
          <p className="linkPreviewTitle"><b>{this.contentArray[0].answer[1].title}</b></p>
          <p className="linkPreviewDesc">{this.contentArray[0].answer[1].content}</p>
          <small className="linkPreviewTimestamp">{this.getTimestamp()}</small>
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="infaTextMain">
          <p className="infaTextMessage">{this.noAnswer}</p>
          <small className="infaTextTimestamp">{this.getTimestamp()}</small>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Using botpress v11.9.5

**Update** with network response.. In this JSON **session.response** is correct but **responses.text** comes as `[object Object]`. So somehow while providing **session.response** to InfaLinkPreview component, this is going wrong.

Please help me figure out what is going wrong in `infa-link-preview.js` or `InfaLinkPreview.jsx` file.

```
{
    "responses": [{
            "type": "custom",
            "module": "custom-component",
            "component": "InfaLinkPreview",
            "text": "[object Object]"
        }
    ],
    "nlu": {
        "entities": [],
        "language": "en",
        "slots": {},
        "intent": {
            "name": "none",
            "confidence": 1,
            "context": "global"
        },
        "intents": [{
                "name": "none",
                "confidence": 1,
                "context": "global"
            }
        ],
        "errored": false,
        "includedContexts": ["global"],
        "ms": 738
    },
    "suggestions": [],
    "state": {
        "user": {},
        "context": {},
        "session": {
            "lastMessages": [{
                    "eventId": "156183685440297440",
                    "incomingPreview": "hii",
                    "replyConfidence": 1,
                    "replySource": "dialogManager",
                    "replyDate": "2019-06-29T19:34:17.244Z",
                    "replyPreview": "#!custom_infatext--mgyiK"
                }, {
                    "eventId": "156183685440297440",
                    "incomingPreview": "hii",
                    "replyConfidence": 1,
                    "replySource": "dialogManager",
                    "replyDate": "2019-06-29T19:34:17.260Z",
                    "replyPreview": "#!builtin_single-choice-FxG4EN"
                }, {
                    "eventId": "156183686163322750",
                    "incomingPreview": "No",
                    "replyConfidence": 1,
                    "replySource": "dialogManager",
                    "replyDate": "2019-06-29T19:34:24.103Z",
                    "replyPreview": "#!custom_infatext-ZSUgWA"
                }, {
                    "eventId": "156183686163322750",
                    "incomingPreview": "No",
                    "replyConfidence": 1,
                    "replySource": "dialogManager",
                    "replyDate": "2019-06-29T19:34:24.106Z",
                    "replyPreview": "#!custom_infatext-bO33uu"
                }, {
                    "eventId": "156183688271887300",
                    "incomingPreview": "How to install secure agent on linux?",
                    "replyConfidence": 1,
                    "replySource": "dialogManager",
                    "replyDate": "2019-06-29T19:34:47.378Z",
                    "replyPreview": "#!custom_linkpreview-Zple6W"
                }
            ],
            "extractedSlots": {},
            "response": [{
                    "answer": {
                        "1": {
                            "content": "this article provides details on how the nnn secure\nagent can be installed on linux the steps are as follows 1 log on to your\nnnn org and download the linux secure agent installer  agent64_install bin 2   log on to linux server as non root user and create a directory the secure agent will be\ninstalled in this directory for example in our environment we logged on\nto linux machine as a non root user admin\nand created a directory mylinuxagent 3 copy the  downloaded agent installer file to the linux server\nand run agent64_install bin as shown in the following screenshots                   4 once the installation is complete navigate to mylinuxagent apps agentcore directory and start the secure agent using the command infaagent\nstartup       5 now run the command consoleagentmanager sh\n  getstatus  to get information on the status of the secure agent   6 the above screenshot indicates that  the secure agent needs to be registered with your\nnnn org run consoleagentmanager sh  configure  and enter  your nnn org username and password   admin aaaa agentcore consoleagentmanager sh configure test nnn com test123\njava_home data admin mylinuxagent apps agentcore jre\nlogin succeeds admin aaaa agentcore consoleagentmanager sh isconfigured\njava_home data admin mylinuxagent apps agentcore jre\ntrue 7 using the commands shown in step 6 above the secure agent should get registered with your nnn org   check the status of the secure agent a couple of times\nusing consoleagentmanager sh getstatus     after some time the status should get changed to ready which indicates that\nthe secure agent has been installed successfully and is fully up and running     8 login to your nnn org configure runtime environments and click on the linux secure agent the process server\nand the data integration server should be up and running       one thing to note is that in the above screenshot the\nprocess server component of the secure agent will be available only if your nnn org is licensed for\nnnn cloud realtime icrt",
                            "source": "KB",
                            "title": "Install nnn Secure Agent on Linux",
                            "url": "https://kb.nnn.com/howto/6/Pages/20/513826.aspx"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "content": "silent install to specified target location can be done by using the following command agent64_install bin i silent duser_install_dir target directory  ",
                            "source": "KB",
                            "title": "Install a Linux secure agent in a specified location using Silent install",
                            "url": "https://ncom/howto/6/Pages/19/5094.aspx"
                        },
                        "3": {
                            "actual_title": "Install and register the Secure Agent on Linux",
                            "content": "",
                            "name": {
                                "NERAction": ["install", "register"],
                                "NERComponent": ["secure_agent"],
                                "NEROS": ["linux"]
                            },
                            "source": "DOC",
                            "title": "Install and register the Secure Agent on Linux",
                            "url": "https://n/install-and-register-the-secure-agent-on-linux.html"
                        }
                    },
                    "query_status": "answer_available"
                }
            ]
        },
        "temp": {}
    },
    "decision": {
        "decision": {
            "reason": "no suggestion matched",
            "status": "elected"
        },
        "confidence": 1,
        "payloads": [],
        "source": "decisionEngine",
        "sourceDetails": "execute default flow"
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be clear that `this.contentArray` is not valid JSON. What the API shows is not relevant. What the browser sees is. Please provide the network panel view of the returned data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below 2 changes and it should work

```
{
    type: 'custom',
    module: 'custom-component',
    component: 'InfaLinkPreview',
    text: data.text,
    response: {
        data
    }
}
```

and

```
contentArray = JSON.parse(this.props.response.data.session.response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna use variable `text` to represent your JSON data. Seems like there is a call of `text.toString()` somewhere in the flow which translates it into `[object Object]` and when you call `JSON.stringify(text)` you get just that. I suggest you look at the whole program flow and check if there is an unecessary `toString()` call somewhere on your JSON object.

Comment: no where I am making a call to `toString` or in this case `JSON.stringify` to the variable `text`